# Setting read_cache_expiry_seconds

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to set the **read_cache_expiry_seconds** option to some user uploads, but the files seems to be cached by 3600 seconds (default) instead the value I want.

The resource context I'm adding is the following:

```
        $_defaultMetadata = [
                            'gs' => [   
                                        'enable_cache' => true,
                                        'enable_optimistic_cache' => false,
                                        'read_cache_expiry_seconds' => 60,
                                        'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=60'
                                    ]
                            ];
        $ctx = stream_context_create($_defaultMetadata);
        file_put_contents( 'gs://' . $bucketPath,  $data, 0 , $ctx);
```

Any idea why this context is not working ?

Comment: How do you know that the items are being cached for 3600 seconds and not 60?

Comment: Because I'm replacing the object and it returns the same headers for an hour (content-length)

Comment: So you mean the Cache-Control header not the read_cache_expiry_seconds value? How are you reading the headers? From a GCS public URL?

Comment: I mean the read_cache_expiry_seconds, not the Cache-Control header. By reading the headers I mean from a public URL, each time I update the object, it delays to give me the right Content-Length value. If I add a URL parameter (?para=randomVal) to the public URL it gives me the correct Content-Lenght value.

Comment: the two are not related - read_cache_expiry_seconds sets how long we store the file in memcache on app engine to make the reads faster. it has nothing to do with serving the file from the public URL.

Comment: Yes, that is clear for me. This question is making reference to memcached on App Engine.

Comment: The question is not clear to me, you talk about "By reading the headers I mean from a public URL, each time I update the object, it delays to give me the right Content-Length value." - which has nothing to do with memcached.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question, the client upload a file (picture), every time the client changes the picture, the same file is overwritten, so the public URL is the same. After the client changes the picture the public URL is returning the previous file, after about an hour the public URL returns the last file uploaded. I'm checking the headers (Content-Length) to evaluate if the file was changed.The 'read_cache_expiry_seconds' option should allow me to see the newest file after 60 seconds of cache, right ?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with it. See "Read through cache" here: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/08/09/whats-new-for-php-runtime-in-the-app-engine-1-8-3-release/

Comment: The answer to my question "Note that we don’t invalidate the cache if the file is changed from outside of your application by directly uploading to the bucket, or on a rename". Thank you