# Google Cloud Storage Public Access Without Caching

Tags: php, google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-storage

I created a website on **Google-Appengine**. To reduce the costs of **Google-Cloud-SQL** my API generates **public** json-files from Cloud-SQL in my **Google-Cloud-Storage** that should be read by my Android-App and my Website (via ajax).

The Problem is, that the files of Google-Cloud-Storage are automatically cached for an hour, but I want to disable caching for specific files.

If I upload a file manual in the Developers Console I may change this behaviour with a click on "Edit Metadata" and setting Cache-Control to `private, max-age=0,no-transform` (see the following picture). Then if I try to access this file, I get the wanted header `private, max-age=0,no-transform`
[image: [Edit Metadata manual]

But in my application the json-files are generated by **PHP** and I always get the header `cache-control → public, max-age=3600`. I create the files with the following code (Here is the official docs: [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced#php_filesystem_functions_support_on_google_cloud_storage)):

```
$options = ['gs' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/json',
    'acl' => 'public-read',
    'enable_cache' => false,
    'read_cache_expiry_seconds' => 0]
];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents($url,$content,0,$ctx);
```

Has anybody an idea why caching is not turned off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mentioned in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710734/setting-read-cache-expiry-seconds), you may need to set `Cache-Control` explicitly/separately in addition to `enable_cache` and `read_cache_expiry_seconds`; in particular, the options you are setting control the App Engine side of caching into [memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/memcache/), whereas the `Cache-Control` setting is [specific to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/memcache/) itself. So you want:

```
$options = ['gs' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/json',
    'acl' => 'public-read',
    'enable_cache' => false,
    'read_cache_expiry_seconds' => 0,
    'Cache-Control' => 'private, max-age=0,no-transform']
];
```

Comment: If use that stream-context I still get the header "public, max-age=3600". Just have a look on this PHP-generated file: [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/total-pad-735/test.json) As described in the related Question, if you add Get-values to the link you get the actual (not-cached) file. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to vote your answer! Your answer is right, but the Cache-Control header did not work with appengine version 1.9.17. This bug was fixed in 1.9.19, so now it works! (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11651)